# Custom UIViewController Transition Not Happening Interactively

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation

I've a custom UIViewController transition which basically stacks the coming ViewController to the right of the current one on the screen and slides them to the left(push) or right(pop).

I've implemented the transition to be interactive:

```
@objc private func addPanGestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let view = gestureRecognizer.view else { return }
    let progress = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: view).x / view.frame.size.width

    switch gestureRecognizer.state {
    case .began:
        interactionController = UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition()
        navigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
    case .changed:
        interactionController.update(progress)
    default:
        if progress >= 0.5 {
            interactionController.finish()
        } else {
            interactionController.cancel()
        }

        interactionController = nil
    }
}
```

The above gesture action initiates my custom transition when I apply a swipe gesture from the left edge of the screen although it doesn't happen interactively but just runs my custom animation completely.

What's causing it not to act interactively?

p.s. The above gesture actions gets added as the action of a `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` to the pushed view controller's view.

Comment: How does the rest of your code look like? Have you implemented *interactionControllerForAnimationController* in your navigation controllers delegate and returned this interactionController?

Comment: @muvaaa Yeah, I did. If I press on to the back button of the navigation controller, it returns nil and if I use my gesture action, it returns the interaction controller as it should.